# Javascript - Creating pyramid array from number values

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am looking to create a pyramid array from number values. The requirement is that I am to work from an array that which in my case has 3 rows with 5 columns. I need to create a pyramid that looks like the example below.

Here is what I want to achieve exactly..

```
[0, 0, 1, 0, 0]
[0, 1, 1, 1, 0]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

So far my code looks something like this..

```js
var a = [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]];

function array_pyramid( array ){
    for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
        for (j = 0; j <= Math.floor(array[i].length / 2); j++){
            var tmp = array[i].length / 2;
            console.log (Math.floor(tmp));
            if ( i < j ) {
                array[i][j] = 1;
            }
        }
    }
    return array;
}

function print_array(array) {
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        console.log(array[i]);
    }
}

//console.log(a);
//print_array(a);
print_array(array_pyramid(a));
```

Comment: Are you sure that the second row of the desired result is supposed to start with a 1 instead of a 0?

Comment: Woops that's my bad (typo) the second row should start with 0

Comment: You should edit your question @Eow

Comment: I have edited sorry now it should be clear :)

Comment: So, are you looking for a general way to make this work with any multi-dimensional array? What happens if there are 6 elements not 5, or if its 5 but has 4 rows? Its easy to write a specific implementation for the array you have included, but making it generic and able to handle all cases....?

Comment: Hi Jamiec, well in my case this is strictly an exercise so I guess working only with 5 elements should do it, but I would of-course love to see other implementations for this concept if that's an option. Cheers!

Comment: *strictly an exercise* - so this is not a real problem, just a totally contrived one?

Comment: Not totally a contrived one this is a real problem, but I require to solve this concept to continue with the particular problem which is at hand, sorry if I have not made myself clear.

Answer (score 1):

Try example below. I purposely kept variable names long and descriptive and kept operations in multiple steps rather than inline for the ease of analyzing.

```js
var a = [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]];

function array_pyramid(array){
    var pBlocksCount = 1;
    var currentRow, rowIndex, columnIndex, columnsCount, rowsCount = array.length;
    for(rowIndex=0; rowIndex<rowsCount; rowIndex++){
        currentRow = array[rowIndex];
        columnsCount = currentRow.length;

        var piramidDrawIndex = parseInt(columnsCount/2);
        var piramidDrawOffset = parseInt(pBlocksCount/2);
        var piramidDrawTrigger = piramidDrawIndex-piramidDrawOffset;
        var blocksToDraw = pBlocksCount;

        for(columnIndex=0; columnIndex<columnsCount; columnIndex++){
            if(columnIndex>=piramidDrawTrigger){
                if(blocksToDraw){
                    currentRow[columnIndex]=1;
                    blocksToDraw--;
                }
            }
        }
        pBlocksCount+=2;
    }
    return array;
}


function print_array(array) {
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        console.log(array[i]);
    }
}

print_array(array_pyramid(a));
```

Answer (score 0):

This will probably fail for most other cases you could come up with, but works in this specific instance:

```
function array_pyramid( array ){
    var mid = Math.floor(array[0].length/2);
    for(var i=0;i<array.length;i++){
        for(var j=0;j<array[i].length;j++){
        var boundsLower = mid-i;
        var boundsUpper = mid+i;
        if(j>=boundsLower && j<=boundsUpper){
            array[i][j] = 1;
        }
      }
    }
    return array;
}
```

Live example: https://jsfiddle.net/o6t1cbdu/

Comment: Brilliant! I am aware that it will not run for more or less elements, but this is exactly what I needed to pass on the logic to my real problem. Much appreciated!

Comment: did you know game ```board snakes and ladders``` ?  how to print number ```[ [1,2,3],[6,5,4],[7,8,9] ]```

Answer (score 0):

Try this ...

```
function array_pyramid(array){
   var limit = [0,0];
   for (var i = array.length - 1, limit = [0, (array[0] || []).length - 1]; i >= 0; i--) {
       for (var j = limit[0]; j <= limit[1]; j++) {
           array[i][j] = 1;
       }
       limit[0]++; limit[1]--;
   }
   return array;
}
```

I hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

You were starting down the right track with an inner and an outer loop, as well as your use of division to try to account for the midpoint.

Here is a verbose and heavily commented modification of your code that **accounts for any number of columns (odd *or* even)** and uses a range that widens during row progression to determine which columns should be 1 or 0. I've included a second array, `b`, to show it works for even column counts as well.

```js
var a = [
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
    ],
    b = [
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
    ];

function array_pyramid (a) {
        // Use first row to determine row length, assume all others are the same
    var base_length = a[0].length,
        // Get a modulus to account for odd or even row length
        mod = base_length % 2,
        // Find the middle point
        mid_point = Math.floor(base_length / 2) + mod,
        // Account for zero-index of arrays
        zero_indexed = mid_point - 1,
        // Produce an initial set of boundaries
        marker_range = {
            lower: zero_indexed,
            upper: (mod === 1) ? zero_indexed : (zero_indexed + 1)
        };

    // Iterate the array's rows
    a.forEach(function (row) {
        // Iterate the row's cols
        row.forEach(function (col, i) {
            // Compare index to boundaries to determine if we're outputting a 1 or a 0
            row[i] = (i >= marker_range.lower && i <= marker_range.upper) ? 1 : 0;
        });

        // If we still have room to expand, widen the range in each direction
        if (marker_range.lower > 0) {
            marker_range.lower -= 1;
            marker_range.upper += 1;
        }
    });

    return a;
}

function print_array(a) {
    var i;

    console.log('-- Start output');

    for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        console.log(' ', a[i]);
    }

    console.log('-- End output');
    console.log(' ');
}

console.log('a (odd col count):');
print_array(array_pyramid(a));

console.log('b: (even col count)');
print_array(array_pyramid(b));
```

Comment: did you know game board snakes and ladders ? how to print number [ [1,2,3],[6,5,4],[7,8,9] ]

Answer (score 0):

So here is my code, it works fine.
The idea is that you find the main vertical center of the matrix and the sideA and sideB variables represent the left and the right side of the pyramid. Once you've found the sides, you make them equal to one as well as everything between them ( `if (j <= sideA && j >= sideB)` ). I hope that helps. :)

```
function array_pyramid ( array ) {
    var item, sideA, sideB;

    if (array instanceof Array) {
        for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            item = array[i];
            centerIndex = Math.floor(item.length / 2);
            sideA = centerIndex + i;
            sideB = centerIndex - i;

            for (var j = 0; j < item.length; j++) {
                if (j <= sideA && j >= sideB) {
                    item[j] = 1;
                }
            }
        }

        return array;

    } else {
        return 'Invalid array';
    }
}

array_pyramid ([
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
]);
```

When you run that code in the console it will return this:

```
[0, 0, 1, 0, 0]
[0, 1, 1, 1, 0]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

And that's it.